# Linux - Subversion - post-commit hook not executing

Tags: linux, svn, archlinux

I am running Arch linux. I have installed Subversion and set it up for use with https everything seems to working fine, with the exception of my hooks.

I have one hook, it is path/to/repo/hooks/post-commit.

It is executable.

I have included a logging statement with: echo "Complete." >> /path/hook.log

When executed as the http user from the command line the script works fine, including the log statement.

When I commit changes I do not see the addition to the log or any of the actions from the rest of the script.

What might I have mis-configured? 
Are there any logs to check for this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you include your complete hook script (simplified, as long as the problem still occurs) in the question?

Comment: I would do a temporary chmod a+x to make sure it wasn't a permissions problem. I suspect that it's not be the http user that needs access.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the proper permission to the /path/hook.log, so as the user that execute the svn-hook, could writte into that file.

But maybe you could give us a litle more information about that hook.